# How to add LibSVM classifier in weka to the classpath in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: classpath, weka, libsvm

I copied the libsvm.jar file to /usr/share/java. Then I edited the /usr/bin/weka as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh

# default options
MAIN_CLASS="weka.gui.GUIChooser"
set_classpath "weka.jar"
export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/libsvm.jar:$CLASSPATH"
run ""
MEMORY="512m"
GUI=""
```

And when i try to classify using libsvm, this is the error i get.

```
java.lang.Exception: libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH!
weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM.buildClassifier(LibSVM.java:1557)
weka.gui.explorer.ClassifierPanel$16.run(ClassifierPanel.java:1432)

at weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM.buildClassifier(LibSVM.java:1557)
at weka.gui.explorer.ClassifierPanel$16.run(ClassifierPanel.java:1432)
```

How can i resolve this classpath issue? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is your actual command line that runs the java executable? you can add the -x flag to #!/bin/bash to print it.

Comment: For adding it LibSVM.jar to the classpath i used 'export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/weka.jar:~/usr/share/java/LibSVM.jar' and the java command to run the weka GUI is 'java -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar:LibSVM.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser'. But i tried using the classifier from the GUI and i still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe try specifying the classpath explicitly with the -classpath flag, without using the $CLASSPATH variable, and check that all the entries exist..

Comment: @GB Thank you! i could solve it by adding the classpath using #export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/libsvm.jar:$CLASSPATH and NOT #export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/weka.jar:~/usr/share/java/LibSVM.jar. Then calling the #java -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar:libsvm.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser from the /usr/share/java directory to start weka since the previous cmd overrides the classpath. :)